# Block matrix 2x2 eigenvalue

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, eigenvalue

There is block matrix Q shape 2 x 2

Q11, Q12, Q21, Q22 square sparse matrix *n x n*.

I need to use this function:

**scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs**

It can take only 2D, if I understood right, but I have **Q.shape - 2×2×n×n**.

Another solvers from **numpy** for example, know **ndarray**, but make it **Q.todense** bad idea. I will be out of RAM.

What can you advise?

Comment: Are  you expecting the behavior the `np.linalg.eig` where `(..., M, M) => (..., M,)`, in effect eigenvalues for each of the 4 blocks?  Why not just iterate on the 4?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean? Does `np.linalg.eig` works with sparse matrices?